# i want to call a method from another class but in same package or file.how to do this?

Tags: java, methods

for ex. i have class A
               class B
               class C
i want to use method defined in class C for objects of class B which is called in Class A.
how to do this?

have look over program?
i am getting error at PRint statement?

```
package com;

    public class CreditCardDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            CreditCardCompany C=new CreditCardCompany();

            customer one=new customer(1 , 11 , 1560);
            customer two =new customer(2,22,3400);
            customer three=new customer(3,33,1600);
            customer four=new customer(4,44,600);
            customer five=new customer(3,33,100);

            System.out.println("Payback amount: "+ getPybackAmount(two));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the line you are getting error in this - `System.out.println("Payback amount: "+ getPybackAmount(two));` ? If so, which class is getPybackAmount()` from and is it static function of that class?

Comment: And what does the error message say? Where is the getPybackAmount() method defined?

Comment: where is `getPybackAmount()` method ? is it static or not ?

Comment: If it is static call using ClassName.getPybackAmount(two)

Comment: How does the code you included relate to the problem. Please include the code for A, B and C

Comment: i think your method is private modifier please change to public modifier

Answer (score 8):

If the method you want to call is `static`, use the class name, a dot, and the method name:

```
TheClass.theMethod();
```

If it's not `static`, then you need an *instance* of the class on which to call it:

```
TheClass t = new TheClass();
t.theMethod();
```

Note that to use a method of a class from an unrelated class in the same package, the method must not be marked `private`. It can have no modifier,  `protected`, or `public`, but it can't be `private`. To use it in an unrelated class in a *different* package, it has to be `public`. Details [in this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> The following table shows the access to members permitted by each modifier.
>
> ```
> Access Levels
> Modifier    Class  Package  Subclass  World
> public        Y       Y        Y        Y
> protected     Y       Y        Y        N
> no modifier   Y       Y        N        N
> private       Y       N        N        N
> ```
>
> The first data column indicates whether the class itself has access to the member defined by the access level. As you can see, a class always has access to its own members. The second column indicates whether classes in the same package as the class (regardless of their parentage) have access to the member. The third column indicates whether subclasses of the class declared outside this package have access to the member. The fourth column indicates whether all classes have access to the member.